# Require module without webpack etc

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, requirejs, es6-modules

How can I load a library that can be loaded only trough require without using webpack, compilation, traspilation, uglification etc.

Let's say: https://github.com/stutrek/scrollMonitor

> The code is vanilla javascript and has no external dependencies, however the script cannot be put in the head.

```
var scrollMonitor = require("scrollmonitor"); // if you're old school you can use the scrollMonitor global.
```

My preferred option would be to do:

```
<script src="./scrollMonitor.js"></script>
```

But that does not work. What is the next easiest option that avoids webpack etc. ?

I tried with ES6 import:

```
import * as scrollMonitor from './scrollMonitor.js';
```

But that returns just empty object.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You need an implementation of `require`. Use WebPack.

Comment: @Quentin I did try WebPack, but I ended up having issues with SourceMaps in Firefox: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1194 I really want to avoid serving browser different code from what I see when I code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it is possible using [getlibs package](http://getlibs.com/):

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/getlibs"></script>
    <script>
         System.import("./script.js");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// script.js
console.log(require('scrollmonitor'));
```

Working example: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aromatic-flamingo

In the script above scrollmonitor is loaded from https://unpkg.com/ however this method works also with local files. I think that solves my problem fully.

Another solution seems to be Pika-Web:

> **A Future Without Webpack**
>
> @pika/web installs modern npm dependencies in a way that lets them run natively in the browser, even if they have dependencies themselves. That’s it. It’s not a build tool and it’s not a bundler (in the traditional sense, anyway). @pika/web is a dependency install-time tool that lets you dramatically reduce the need for other tooling and even skip Webpack or Parcel entirely.
>
> It all comes down to a tradeoff between performance, caching efficiency, and how much complexity you feel comfortable with. And again, this is the entire point of @pika/web: Add a bundler because it makes sense to your situation, not because you have no other choice.
>
> @pika/web checks your package.json manifest for any "dependencies" that export a valid ESM “module” entry point, and then installs them to a local web_modules/ directory. @pika/web works on any ESM package, even ones with ESM & Common.js internal dependencies.

https://www.pika.dev/blog/pika-web-a-future-without-webpack/

However, it works only with a valid ESM "module" entry point. Not the case with scrollMonitor.

Comment: Note that Pika-Web has been superseded by [Snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/).

Comment: Note that Snowpack is no longer maintained. See [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) and [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/). This comment will probably be outdated next month.

Answer (score 0):

> My preferred option would be to do:
>
> ```
> <script src="./scrollMonitor.js"></script>
> ```
>
> But that does not work.

This variant is supported by the library, but it shouldn't be put into **head**. Just try to add it to the end of **body**. Also the global variable `scrollMonitor` should appear.

Comment: I may be doing something silly, but it does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/h37qps59/

Answer (score 0):

That package includes a fallback global, so you can do this:

```
import './scrollMonitor';
```

This makes `scrollMonitor` available on the window object for you work with.